# Problems installing bassaudio library with npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install [bassaudio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bassaudio) library to my project, and npm throws an error every time I try to install it, whatever I tried until now to make it work.
I have the following error when I npm install bassaudio :

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe failed with exit code: 1 
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23) 
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20) 
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12) 
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041 
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" 
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\myusername\projectname\node_modules\ref 
gyp ERR! node -v v14.13.1 
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0 
gyp ERR! not ok npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
npm ERR! errno 1 
npm ERR! ref@1.3.5 install: node-gyp rebuild 
npm ERR! Exit status 1 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ref@1.3.5 install script. 
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR! C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-10-15T12_22_17_205Z-debug.log
```

The log file is enormous and repeat this error at its end, so, not sure it would be relevant to copy paste it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : For the next person trying to use bassaudio, or bassaudiolibrary, the first one isn't maintained to recent node/npm version, and the second is up to date, but incomplete.
I made a new package, bassaudio-updated which is updated and as complete as the other both libraries combined. I have only tested if for my needs yet, but I stay availaible if some problems occurs. :)